# Adding 3rd party framework in Xcode 7

Tags: frameworks, xcode7-beta5

Xcode 7's setting are a bit different.

- I reference the framework in the file tree.
- in Framework Search Path: /Applications/Adobe\ Gaming\ SDK\ 1.3/AIRSDK\ 18/runtimes/air/mac
- set Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules : yes
- in my header (target public) I added #import

But I keep getting "Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'myFrame'" on the #import when compiled. The dependent files seems to see framework while I'm coding.

Not sure what else to set.

thanks.